# Symplectic orthogonality and projective duality: how do they work together?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry

Let $(V,\omega)$ be a $2n$-dimensional linear symplectic space, and $(\mathbb{P}V,\theta_\omega)$ the corresponding $(2n-1)$-dimensional contact manifold.

Given a smooth $(n-1)$-dimensional smooth projective variety $X\subset \mathbb{P}V$, I can define its **orthogonal**
$$
X^\perp:=\{ \pi\in \mathbb{P}V^*\mid\pi=v^\perp\textrm{ for some }[v]\in X  \}\, ,
$$
as well as its **dual**
$$
X^\ast:=\{ \pi\in \mathbb{P}V^*\mid\pi\supset T_v\widehat{X}\textrm{ for some }[v]\in X  \}\, ,
$$
where $\widehat{X}$ is the cone over $X$.

Here's the point: I'm trying to define a "companion" $X_\bullet$ of $X$ via the equation
$$
X_\bullet^\ast=X^\perp\, .\quad\quad (1)
$$
*Example.* If $D<V$ is a linear $n$-dimensional subspace, and $X=\mathbb{P}D$, then $(1)$ unambiguously defines $X_\bullet$, which turns out to be $\mathbb{P}D^\perp$. In particular, if $D$ is $\omega$-Lagrangian, then $X_\bullet=X$ is also $\theta_\omega$-Legendrian.

> QUESTION: how to characterise the $X$'s possessing a well-defined (by means of $(1)$) "companion" $X_\bullet$? In particular, does this property hold for arbitrary (i.e., not necessarily linear) $\theta_\omega$-Legendrian $X$'s? Is it true that in this case $X=X_\bullet$?

I'm sure that this problem has been already addressed somewhere: any reference/keyword will be most welcome.

**EDITED after Libli's and Robert Bryant's comments**

Of course, by using the *reflexivity theorem* (see, e.g., [this paper by Tevlev, Theorem 1.7a](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0112028v1)), one can solve $(1)$ and obtain
$$
X_\bullet=(X^\perp)^*\, .
$$
So, the answer to my question is "for all $X$". Nevertheless (recall that I'm assuming $X$ to be smooth), I can still ask, how to characterise those $X$ whose $X_\bullet$ enjoys some extra properties, like being smooth and (which this is **what really I'm interested in**) having the same dimension as $X$ - or even being $X$ itself (the only purpose of the symplectic orthogonality is to have $X$ and its dual sitting in the same space, and compare them).

Comment: Of course that $X^\perp$ is just $X$, but without this passage I cannot compare $X$ with its dual, or - if you prefer - conormal, which is essential for my purposes. So, if you want to bypass the identification $V^*=V$, then I'm just asking if there is some obvious differential invariant associated with a variety $Y$, for instance, in $\mathbb{P}^3$, whose vanishing is a necessary (or even sufficient) condition for $Y$ to be the the conormal variety of another variety $X$. And possibly a method to recover $X$ out of $Y$... What is the standard reference for this kind of business?

Comment: @RobertBryant : usually, people use conormal for the incidence in $\mathbb{P}(V) \times \mathbb{P}(V^*)$. The dual "variety" also usually refers to the projection of the conormal in $\mathbb{P}(V^*)$. So here, Giovanni really talks about the dual and not the conormal.

Comment: @GiovanniMoreno : if I understood correctly your question, given any (smooth?) variety $Y \subset \mathbb{P}(V)$, you want to know conditions on $Y$ such that $Y$ would be the dual of some $X \subset \mathbb{P}(V^*)$?

If you don't put any conditions on $X$, then this is always true as the biduality theorem tells you that $(Y^*)^* = Y$.

If you want furthermore $X$ and $Y$ to be smooth, this is more intricate. For instance a smooth quadric is dual to a smooth quadric, $Gr(2,5)$ is dual to $Gr(2,5)$. I am not sure there is a classification of these.

Comment: @GiovanniMoreno : some references :

_ Zak : Tagents and Secants of Algebraic Varieties,
_Tevelev : Projective duality and homegenous spaces,
_ Holweck PhD's thesis

Comment: @Libli:  I see that I was mistaken about the terminology.  Thanks for the correction.  Since I can't fix my original comment, I'll just delete it.

Comment: @RobertBryant : I don't know if it' a good idea to delete your first comment. Now, Giovanni's answer and mine are meaningless...

Comment: @Libli : I kind of feel ashamed now, for I had all the time the Tevelev's paper in my e-library, and I never thought of looking at it! Of course, you're right: the - how he calls it - "reflexivity theorem" allows one to 'solve the equation' $(1)$ by starring both members: $X_\bullet:=(X^\perp)^*$. So, the answer to my first question is: "for all $X$" - as you said. Thanks.

Comment: @Libli : I also think it's a pity that the first Robert Bryant's comment has disappeared. After all, the incidence correspondence in $\mathbb{P}V\times \mathbb{P}V^*$ covers both $X$ and $X^*$, so that the distinction between 'conormal' and 'dual' is very soft. Besides, he made some comments about developables (related to my updated question above) which I found interesting, but now I cannot recall them... It reminds me of the Siths erasing the whereabouts of planet Kamino from the Jedi archives: now all surrounding comments are still pulled towards it, but the central comment has gone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Corrected (Partial) Answer**

Given a smooth variety $X\subset \mathbb{P}V$ that is the projectivization of a smooth punctured cone $\hat X\subset V\setminus\{0\}$, the space $X_\bullet$ that the OP defines is a variety in $\mathbb{P}V$ described as
$$
X_\bullet 
= \bigl\{[v]\in\mathbb{P}V\ \bigl|\ \exists w\in \hat X,\ \ \omega(v,T_w\hat X) = 0\ \bigr\}
\subset \mathbb{P}V.
$$
The OP's question then is: When is $X_\bullet = X$?  (In this case, say $X$ is $\omega$-self-dual.)  [Note that the question of when $X_\bullet$ is smooth or has the same dimension as $X$ is not really a symplectic question, since the classical dual $X^*\subset\mathbb{P}V^*$ is equivalent to $X_\bullet$ under the correlation defined by $\omega$, and $X^*$ does not depend on the symplectic structure.]

I don't have a complete answer, but here are a couple of observations:

1. If $X$ is $\omega$-self-dual, we must have $\dim X \ge n{-}1$, 
   and, if $\dim X = n-1$, then $X = \mathbb{P}L$, 
   where $L\subset V$ is a Lagrangian subspace of $V$.
   The reason for this is that, if $\dim X = k$, then the
   dimension of $T_w\hat X$ is $k+1$, 
   so its symplectic orthogonal $(T_w\hat X)^\perp$
   has dimension $2n-k-1$ 
   and so $\mathbb{P}\bigl((T_w\hat X)^\perp\bigr)$ has
   dimension $2n-k-2$ and is contained in $X_\bullet$.
   Thus, if $X_\bullet = X$ (or, more generally, if they just have the same dimension), then $k\ge 2n-k-2$, so $k\ge n{-}1$.
   If equality holds then $X = X_\bullet 
   = \mathbb{P}\bigl((T_w\hat X)^\perp\bigr)$, so $X = \mathbb{P}L$
   for the Lagrangian space $L = (T_w\hat X)^\perp = T_w\hat X$.
2. If $\dim X = 2n{-}2$ (i.e., $X$ is a hypersurface), 
   then $X$ must be a quadric hypersurface 
   (since those are the only smooth hypersurfaces whose duals are smooth), 
   but not every quadric hypersurface is $\omega$-self-dual when $n>1$:
   The set of smooth quadric hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}V$ 
   has dimension $n(2n{+}1)-1$ while the space of $\omega$-self-dual 
   quadric hypersurfaces only has dimension $n(n{+}1)$.
   In fact, it is not hard to show
   that if $V = L_+\oplus L_-$ is a splitting of $V$ 
   into two transverse Lagrangian subspaces $L_+$ and $L_-$, 
   then the quadric hypersurface defined by
   $$
   X = \bigl\{ [v_+ + v_-]\in\mathbb{P}V\ \bigl|\ \omega(v_+,v_-) = 0\ \bigr\}
   $$
   is $\omega$-self-dual, and every $\omega$-self-dual quadric
   hypersurface is of this form for some splitting $V = L_+\oplus L_-$.

Comment: Now the Force is back into balance! I like, in particular, the 1st observation: me and my friends long suspected it was so, but none of us was able to find such a simple argument to prove it! As you may guess, we are interested into applications to 2nd order nonlinear PDEs: if $V$ is the contact plane in $J^1(2,1)$, and $X$ is 1-dimensional, then $X$ determines in a natural way an hypersurface in $J^2(2,1)$, and you have just proved that $X$ is $\omega$-self-dual if and only if the hypersurface is a parabolic Monge-Ampere equation...

Comment: ... Then, you're right: the "non-symplectic" part of my question is purely algebraic-geometric, and requires different tools (the 2nd observation of yours, though correct, is not useful when it comes to PDEs, since, if $X$ is "too big", then the corresponding PDE is trivial). Speaking of which, as you like so much discussing this stuff, why don't you join us into a dedicated workshop (https://www.impan.pl/en/sites/gmoreno/home/workshop-2016) we are organising in Warsaw? Pawel Nurowski and Gianni Manno have both sent you an invitation, a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: @GiovanniMoreno:  So what dimensions are you interested in?  I thought a (very) little about the intermediate dimensions (between $n{-}1$ and $2(n{-}1)$), but haven't had free time to do more than make very simple observations.  If you had some specific dimensions, that might make it easier.   As for the workshop, it sounds very interesting, but I just wrote to you, Pawel, and Gianni to explain that it's during a very inconvenient week for me, which is too bad because I would have liked to have participated.

Comment: in the case $n=4$ (i.e., when $V$ is the contact plane in $J^1(2,1)$), I'm interested in curves $X$ in $\mathbb{P}V$. Indeed, such a curve determines the 2-fold (surface) $\mathcal{E}_X:=\{ L\subset V\mid \omega|_L\equiv 0, \mathbb{P}L\cap X\neq\emptyset\}$ in the Lagrangian Grassmannian $L(V)$ of $V$ (which is a 3-fold). Basically, I'm trying to understand to what extent such surfaces in $L(V)$ can be studied through the corresponding curves $X$ in $\mathbb{P}V$. And the first question is: how to test an arbitrary surface $\mathcal{E}$ to be of the form $\mathcal{E}_X$? ...

Comment: ... and I guess that the answer is somehow buried in this work of Dennis The (http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.1364), where he cooks out a differential invariant whose vanishing is a necessary condition for $\mathcal{E}$ to be - as he puts it - singly ruled. In turn, this "singly-ruledness" should guarantee the existence of a curve $X$ such that $\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{E}_X$, but I could not yet work out the details (and Dennis himself could not help much). [The main reason I planned this workshop was to answers questions like these (and, as I explained in my email, there can be other chances to meet)]

Comment: [these non-editable comments are really annoying: above I meant $n=2$, of course!]

Comment: With $n=3$ and beyond, the situation becomes more intricate, and I barely touched it. It goes also beyond the scope of the OP, as $\mathbb{P}V$ needs to be replaced with $Gr_\omega(V,n-1)$, the Grassmannian of $(n-1)$-dimensional $\omega$-isotropic subspaces of $V$ (carrying a contact form $\theta_\omega$ inherited by $\omega)$. As before, $Gr_\omega(V,n-1)$ contains very special $n-1$-dimensional varieties $X$, namely the (standard) Grassmannians $Gr(L,n-1)$, with $L$ Lagrangian subspace of $V$, and the corresponding $\mathcal{E}_X$ is once again an $n$-dim parabolic Monge-Ampere equation...

Comment: ... and now I'm sure that the problem of characterising, e.g., the 5-folds $\mathcal{E}$ in the 6-dimensional Lagrangian Grassmannian (i.e., with $n=3$), which can be brought to the form $\mathcal{E}_X$, with $\dim X=2$, can be dealt with in terms of $GL_2$-structures, as Abraham D. Smith did in his work (http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.2789).

Answer (score 3):

Varieties having the same dimension as their duals have been classified by Ein (see http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01391495). They are:

_hypersurfaces,

_$\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^{n-1} \subset \mathbb{P}^{2n-1}$;

_$G(2,5) \subset \mathbb{P}^9$,

_$\mathbb{S}_{10} \subset \mathbb{P}^{15}$.

EDIT : this results holds if one assumes the variety non-degenerate (that is non-included in a hyperplane).

Comment: You seem to be missing some (probably very simple) nondegeneracy hypothesis or case.  After all, the dual of $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb{P}^{2n-1}$ is another $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$ (in the dual $\mathbb{P}^{2n-1}$, of course), and that's not on your list.

Comment: @Libli: nice reference, thanks! As I have explained in my last comments to Robert Bryant's answer, I'm mostly interested in curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$, whereas, for higher values of $n$, the space $\mathbb{P}^{2n-1}$ has to be replaced by ``something more general''. Nevertheless, after your remark, it seems that the only curves in $\mathbb{P}^3$ having one-dimensional duals, are $\mathbb{P}^1$'s (as just observed by Bryant), which happen to be $\omega$-self-dual iff the $\mathbb{P}^1$'s are the projectivizations of Lagrangian planes (see below).